# LINQ Query for Controlling some item

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have got a windows forms project in C#. There are 2 text boxes on my form.
First text box for Name and second is for surname.

Whenever user presses over TAB button **I want to check from Database if there is a name like my first textbox's.text**. If there is, then it will move to next control. If it is not then my program will ask for saving this name to DB with LINQ to SQL ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to attach to the Validating event on the Control.

Answer (score 0):

On the `ExitFocus` event(not sure about the event name) of the first textbox do a select from the DB for the text in the textbox.

If your Count is 0 show a message box to the user prompting him to check whether he wants to save the username or else get the surname and populate it in the second textbox

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define and attach the `Leave` event of the first text box (let's say its id is `textBox1`) as shown below:

```
        this.textBox1.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_Leave);
```

Then in its corresponding leave event handler you can write appropriate logic to check if the name entered by the user already exists in the database using LINQ to SQL or not. Based on the findings you can take appropriate decision using `if` statement as shown below:

```
        private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataClasses1DataContext linqToSqlDataContext = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            if (linqToSqlDataContext.employees.Any(x => x.Name == textBox1.Text))
            {
                //move focus to surname text box control as the name already exists in DB
                textBox2.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                //add a new entity into database for the name entered by the user
                linqToSqlDataContext.employees.Attach(new employee { Name = textBox1.Text });
                linqToSqlDataContext.SubmitChanges();

            }
        }
```